# Check if multiple mysql tables exist

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to check with Mysql, if 3 tables exist but somehow this does not work with more then 1 table? How can I check if 3 tables exist?

```
Select count(*) From information_schema.tables
    where table_schema = 'userbook' and table_name = 'entry'
    and table_name = 'stats' and table_name = 'user';
```

I'm working with the MySQL-Connector and Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your are looking for a table that has the name `entry` the name `stats` and the name `user` - all at the same time. Your COUNT will always be 0 on this!

You need to use the `OR` operator like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
  table_schema = 'userbook' AND 
  (table_name = 'entry' OR
   table_name = 'stats' OR
   table_name = 'user')
```

You can also use `IN`, which is a little bit easier to maintain:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
  table_schema = 'userbook' AND 
  table_name IN ('entry','stats','user')
```

In both cases: If the count is 3, then all three tables exist.